# Increasing table width and centering word within column using longtable package

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, width

**Problems:**

- Increasing table width to 100%
- Centering table header word (i.e. criteria)
- Repeating table captions on every page

**Questions:**

1. How do I increase table width to 100%?
2. How do I center the word `criteria` so it falls exactly in the `center` of the letters `A to L`?
3. Is it possible to make so captions are printed out below the table for each page?

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\begin{longtable}{cccccccccccccc}
\caption{Table caption here}\label{chap1:tab1}

\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{14}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\multicolumn{14}{c}{}\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{14}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

\toprule
   \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Criteria}} \\
\midrule
   \textbf{Solutions} & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L \\
\midrule
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
\end{longtable}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}X}
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont 
    \textbf{A:} Caption 1\newline 
    \textbf{B:} Caption 2\newline 
    \textbf{C:} Caption 3\newline 
    \textbf{D:} Caption 4\newline 
    \textbf{E:} Caption 5 & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont 
    \textbf{F:} Caption 6\newline 
    \textbf{G:} Caption 7\newline 
    \textbf{H:} Caption 8\newline 
    \textbf{I:} Caption 9 & 
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont 
    \textbf{J:} Caption 10\newline 
    \textbf{K:} Caption 11\newline 
    \textbf{L:} Caption 12\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved 1 and 2. For 3, I am confused and think that that won't be a nice idea. However, you may add custom text along side `continued on next page`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable,booktabs}
%\usepackage{ctable}       %% don't use this



\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccccccccc}
\caption{Table caption here}\label{chap1:tab1}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{13}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{13}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

\toprule
 &  \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Criteria}} \\
\midrule
   \textbf{Solutions} & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L \\
\midrule
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\
\end{longtable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}X}
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont
    \textbf{A:} Caption 1\newline
    \textbf{B:} Caption 2\newline
    \textbf{C:} Caption 3\newline
    \textbf{D:} Caption 4\newline
    \textbf{E:} Caption 5 &
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont
    \textbf{F:} Caption 6\newline
    \textbf{G:} Caption 7\newline
    \textbf{H:} Caption 8\newline
    \textbf{I:} Caption 9 &
    \fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont
    \textbf{J:} Caption 10\newline
    \textbf{K:} Caption 11\newline
    \textbf{L:} Caption 12\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, it wouldn't look good at all. Thank you for your time, highly appreciated!